# Search for href parameter in rich text field

Tags: craft3, search

I'm trying to find using [craft search](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/searching.html) "bitly" urls in body rich-text field in articles. It's for generation of list of popular articles.
So if query is a link (like "http://bit.ly/1eZFQMY") search doesn't find anything.

Tried "fuzzy" search and all methods listed on [craft search](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/searching.html) page.

Answer (score 1):

Before Craft saves any keywords in the `craft_searchindex` table in the database, that content goes through a normalization process, including things like removing punctuation.

So the link "http://bit.ly/1eZFQMY" will actually get normalized to `http bit ly 1ezfqmy`.

If you really wanted to find all entries with bitly URLs in them, then using `"http bit ly"` should work.